# Loading a android kernel module with vermagic mismatch

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

For a phone there are few modules which are proprietary and aren't licenced under GPL and sources of them are not provided with the kernel sources. So my problem is when I add a custom kernel name or add a upstream patch, there is change in version magic of the kernel and it doesnt match with that of proprietary modules and there is a version magic mismatch for these modules and they don't get loaded.

So is there any workaround for this except manually retaining the vermagic of the kernel with that those of modules? The module is ofcourse compatible with the kernel as it is meant for it, just this vermagic mismatch is causing issue

Also there is no way of force loading a module for an Android kernel. Anyone of you have solution for this?

Comment: Assuming that your are building a custom module (.ko) and pushing it to /lib/modules, what kernel errors are you seeing?

Comment: I am not building a custom module. Probably you didn't understand my question

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid loading modules into a kernel with different version magic strings.

The module may have internal kernel interfaces with other kernel resources/modules that may break with different kernel version. And this could REALLY break your system/kernel.

If you want to take the risk, then use a kernel version as close as possible to your module version and load your module with:

```
modprobe -f module-name
```

`-f` will bypass the vermagic check.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the vermagic variable in module info section. You would need an hex editor or [this software](https://github.com/D1W0U/vermagic) and the new version string to be less or equal to the oldest one.